# Canvas. Align text

Tags: javascript, canvas

This code would satisfy me but for the text alignment. Both the top line and bottom line are not aligned in the center of the lines. Could you help me here?

```js
function redrawMeme(image, topLine, bottomLine) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.textAlign = "center";

  var height = Math.min(image.height, canvas.height);
  var width = Math.min(image.width, canvas.width);

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

  var font = "bold 24px verdana, sans-serif ";
  ctx.font = font;

  var fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;

  var strokeStyle = "black";

  if (topLine) {
    ctx.fillText(topLine, 50, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(topLine, 50, 50);
  };

  if (bottomLine) {
    ctx.fillText(bottomLine, 50, 350);
    ctx.strokeText(bottomLine, 50, 350);
  };
}

// The following code is just for the example:
const img = new Image(500, 500);
img.src = 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/500/abott@adorable.png';

img.onload = function() {
  redrawMeme(img, 'Top', 'Bottom');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because canvas text is center-aligned, so the left and right ends of each line depends on the text length. You can align them by setting their x coordinates to the center of the width, like this:

```js
function redrawMeme(image, topLine, bottomLine) {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.textAlign = "center";

  var height = Math.min(image.height, canvas.height);
  var width = Math.min(image.width, canvas.width);

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

  var font = "bold 24px verdana, sans-serif ";
  ctx.font = font;

  var fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;

  var strokeStyle = "black";

  var centerX = width / 2

  if (topLine) {
    ctx.fillText(topLine, centerX, 50);
    ctx.strokeText(topLine, centerX, 50);
  };

  if (bottomLine) {
    ctx.fillText(bottomLine, centerX, 350);
    ctx.strokeText(bottomLine, centerX, 350);
  };
}

// The following code is just for the example:
const img = new Image(500, 500);
img.src = 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/500/abott@adorable.png';

img.onload = function() {
  redrawMeme(img, 'Top', 'Bottom');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```